# iOS Application tried to present modally an active controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a view controller modally from another view controller that is the second view inside UINavigationController. 
But it keep giving error and crashing. Application tried to present modally an active controller

I dont know what does it mean. Following is the way how i am calling.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    FBPreviewPostViewController *previewPostViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FBPreviewPostViewController"];
    previewPostViewController.delegate = self;
    previewPostViewController.selectedImg = selectedImage;
    [self presentViewController:previewPostViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please paste complete crash message ?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <FBTimeLineViewController: 0xb375db0>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1fc5012 0x1985e7e 0x9b3111 0x9b4167 0x2a035 0x13835b3 0x1f84376 0x1f83e06 0x1f6ba82 0x1f6af44 0x1f6ae1b 0x24a17e3 0x24a1668 0x8c9ffc 0x26a5 0x25d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the view controller is presented twice, which is not allowed.

I don't know much about Storyboards and your app, perhaps `FBPreviewPostViewController` has been presented by storyboards. You can check whether it is in view hierarchy by checking `viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window` is true or not.

BTW, you are using storyboards, why don't use segue?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will check the view hierarchy. I am not using segue because i am calling that viewcontroller from action sheet button call.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following code

```
NSString *stbName = [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary  objectForKey:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"];
UIStoryboard *Mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:stbName bundle:nil];
FBPreviewPostViewController *previewPostViewController = [Mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FBPreviewPostViewController"];
previewPostViewController.delegate = self;
previewPostViewController.selectedImg = selectedImage;
[self presentModalViewController:previewPostViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Both your way and the OP's way of getting the storyboard are needlessly complex. You can just use self.storyboard.

Comment: Deepesh: Whats different in those lines of code ? it looks similar only first line is different. Also presentModalViewController is deprecated since iOS 6.